# Python process will not exit

Tags: python, nosetests

I'm use nosetests to run some tests.  However, after the tests have finished running, the nosetests process just sits there, and will not exit.  Is there anyway to diagnose this?  Does Python have a facility similar to sending Java a kill -QUIT which will print a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter the debugger and type `bt`:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Then you can step through the operation and see where it hangs.

Answer (score 4):

```
nosetests -vv -x -s --pdb test_foo
```

where *-x* is "Stop running tests after the first error or failure" and *--pdb* is **"Drop into debugger on failures or errors"**

Also see http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: I also have to press Ctrl+D for some test that do **subprocess** calls.